# retrieving documents from applications directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
NSURL* suppurl = [manager URLForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:nil];


NSString *path = [suppurl path];
NSLog(@" Path %@",path);


NSString* myfolder = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFolder"];

NSDirectoryEnumerator* myFolderDir = [manager enumeratorAtPath:myfolder]; 
for (NSString* file in myFolderDir)
{

    NSLog(@" file %@",file);

    NSString *getImagePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",file]];

    BOOL exists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:getImagePath];
    NSLog(@" image path %@",getImagePath);

    if (exists)
    {
        NSLog(@" exists");
    }
```

The first `NSLog(@" file %@",file);` successfully logs the file name... but the BOOL exists doesn't .

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are enumerating files in `myFolderDir`, but then you are trying to verify if an equally-named file exists in `path`. Replace with:

```
NSString *getImagePath = [myFolderDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",file]];
```

Also, note that you don't need to do this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",file]
```

.. `file` already being an `NSString`.

In case you're trying to enumerate images in that folder, consider testing the file extension:

```
if ([[file pathExtension] isEqualToString: @"jpg"]) {
    // load the image
    [self loadImage: [myFolderDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:file]];
}
```